# Lumen 5.6.4 get post route throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, lumen-5.4

whenever i try to access my url for a post in Lumen through the browser or postman i get the below error

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException

in RoutesRequests.php 
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(2, array('POST')))
in RoutesRequests.php
```

see route code from web.php below

```
 $router->post('gen','VoucherController@generateVoucherCode');
```

see code from generateVoucherCode

```
class VoucherController extends Controller
{


    public function generateVoucherCode(Request $request){
// generate 16 digit random no.
    $random1 = rand(1111, 9999);
    $random2 = rand(1111, 9999);
    $random3 = rand(1111, 9999);
    $random4 = rand(1111, 9999);
    $voucher_code = ($random1."-".$random2."-".$random3."-".$random4);

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $use_once = "yes";
    $request->request->add( ['voucher_code' => $voucher_code,
        'use_once' => $use_once,
        'date_used' => $today,
        'date_created' => $today]);

        Voucher_code::create($request->all());

    return response()->json($voucher_code);
    }
```

Can someone pls tell me what I am doing wrongly

Comment: Try doing artisan routes:list so it can show you what routes are actually defined.

Comment: Hi Chris, I ran the command "php artisan route:list"

The response was
  There are no commands defined in the "route" namespace.

what should i do. I am kind of new at Lumen

Comment: This is my routes/web.php code

Comment: <?php
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function($router)
{

    $router->group(['prefix' => 'vouchers'], function($router)
    {

    $router->post('gen/{expiry_date,percentage_discount}','VoucherController@generateVoucherCode');

    $router->get('start','VoucherController@index');
});

});